# Handling invalid fields in Firefox when submitting a form with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form with an `<input type=number>` field.
The form is not submitted via `<button type=submit>`, but the input field values are collected with a Javascript function and passed to an AJAX call. In a classical submit, Firefox would prevent me from submitting the form when one of the input fields is invalid. But in this case it doesn't happen. Instead, Firefox sets the invalid field value as empty. As my parameter isn't required, I can't distinguish on the server side whether it was invalid or just intentionally left out. A small working sketch of what my program does:

```html
<html><head><meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").click(
    function() {
      let data = {somefield: $("#field").val()};
      console.log("data to transfer:", data);
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http://httpbin.org/post",
        data: data,
        success: function(e) {
          console.log("server response:", e.form);
        }
      });
    }
  );
});
</script></head><body><form>
<input id="field" type="number" />
<button type="button" id="button">Submit</button>
</form></body></html>
```

Chrome handles this situation better -- it doesn't allow me typing non-number characters in number fields. Trying to emulate this behaviour with jQuery bears other problems that would probably be worth another question.

What would be the best way to handle this in Firefox?

Comment: add pattern attribute to the input field number `pattern="/^\d+$/"

Comment: You could also create a hidden input - `<input type="hidden" value="none" />` with the same `name` attribute as your number input and place it before the rest of the inputs. That way it will always be submitted with a value - "none" or a number.

Comment: @BearNithi Mh, that doesn't seem to have any impact on the problem.